# Continuity of $\|f\|_p^p$ on the set where it is finite

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Fix a function $f$ that is complex measurable on $X$, with the positive measure $\mu$ on $X$.

Define $\phi:(0,\infty) \to [0,\infty]$ as $\displaystyle \phi(p) = \int_X |f|^p d \mu$, and define $E=\{p|\phi(p)<\infty\} $.

It is easy to prove that $\log \circ \phi$ is convex on the set $E$ using Hoelder's inequality, and hence it follows that $\phi$ is convex on E, and so $\phi$ is continuous on $E^{\circ}$ (i.e. the interior of $E$). Note that the convexity of $\phi$ implies that $E$ is a connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now my problem is in showing that $\phi$ is continuous on $\partial E \cap E$, the boundary points that $E$ contains, as well, but I have no idea how to proceed.

I feel like the solution should be really easy and I'm missing something really obvious, but I don't know what.
My intuition also tells me that $E$ should probably be open (and hence $\partial E \cap E=\varnothing$), and I strongly feel that this is true, but how do I prove it?

The condition that $\partial E \cap E=\varnothing$ is also equivalence to $\sup E \notin E$ and $\inf E \notin E$, and even though that looks kinda obvious and intuitive, I'm too incompetent to prove it.

This is a problem from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Isn't E a convex set?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that helps since convex sets and connected sets are the same thing in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It means that $E$ is an interval. You just need to  show that if $\sup E \in E$ then $\phi$ is (left-) continuous there. Same with the infimum.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A= \{|f|\le 1\}, B =\{|f|>1\}.$ Suppose $p_1,p_2 \in E, p_1 < p_2.$ Then for $p\in [p_1,p_2]$,

$$\tag 1 |f|^p \le |f|^{p_1}\chi_A + |f|^{p_2}\chi_B.$$

This shows $f\in L^p,$ hence $[p_1,p_2]\subset E.$ Thus $E$ is an interval.

To prove continuity on $[p_1,p_2],$ let $q\in [p_1,p_2].$ Then we have $|f|^p \to |f|^q$ pointwise on $X$ as $p \to q.$ Because we have a fixed dominating $L^1$ function given by $(1),$ the domintated convergence theorem shows $\int_X|f|^p \to \int_X|f|^q$ as $p\to q$ within $[p_1,p_2].$ Thus $\phi$ is continuous on any compact subinterval of $E,$ which shows $\phi$ is continuous on $E.$

PS: $E$ need not be open. For example define $f(x) = 1/[x(\ln x)^2]$ on $(0,1/2).$ Then $E= (0,1].$